# rewrite url. asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, asp.net-routing

how to rewrite url string. 
in asp.net with c#.net.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET supports URL rewriting via [System.Web.Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.aspx), it is not just for ASP.NET MVC.

See [How to: Use Routing with Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202.aspx) on MSDN.

To have URL ~/foo handled by page ~/example/foo.aspx register the route in global.asax.cs

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Route r = new Route("{Parameter}", new ExampleRouteHandler());
    Routes.Add(r);
}
```

And the route handler might look like this:

```
public class ExampleRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        string page = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("Parameter");

        if (page == "") {
            page = "default";
        }

        string @virtual = string.Format("~/example/{0}.aspx", page);

        return (Page)BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(@virtual, typeof(Page));
    }
}
```