# How to generate complex url like stackoverflow?

Tags: url, playframework

I'm using playframework, and I hope to generate complex urls like stackoverflow. For example, I want to generate a question's url:

```
http://aaa.com/questions/123456/How-to-generator-a-complex-url
```

Note the last part, it's the title of the question.

But I don't know how to do it.

**UPDATED**

In the playframework, we can define routes in `conf/routes` file, and what I do is:

`GET    /questions/{<\d+>id}    Questions.show`

In this way, when we call `@{Questions.show(id)}` in views, it will generate:

`http://aaa.com/questions/123456`

But how to let the generated has a **title** part, is difficult.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With playframework it's easy to generate such url. In your routes file you add this :

```
GET /questions/{id}/{title}       YourController.yourMethod
```

See the doc in playframework site about routing for more info

In your html page :

```
<a href="@{YourController.yourMethod(id,title.slugify())}">
```

slugify method from JavaExtensions, clean your title from reserved characters ([see doc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/javaextensions#aslugifya))

Answer (score 2):

It a server-side url rewriter does. In case of SO it doesn't matter you type [{...}/questions/4698625/how-to-generate-complex-url-like-stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698625/how-to-generate-complex-url-like-stackoverflow) or [{...}/questions/4698625](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698625) - they both redirects to the same content. So this postfix is used just to increase readability of a url.

To see more details about url rewriting, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370207/rewrite-url-asp-net-c).

**UPD:**
to generate such a postfix,

1. take a title of the content,
2. shrink multiple whitespaces into single
3. replace all whitespaces with dash (-)
4. remove all non-letter symbols from a title

Better to perform this operations with Regular Expressions

Comment: thank you, but the difficult part is how to do it in playframework.